# How get JSON from Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, ajax, json, laravel-5.1

I'm developing an application with Laravel 5.1 and I try to get information from json but i can't, i have the next code:

Routes:

```
Route::get('toys','ToyController@listing');
```

Controller:

```
    public function listing(){
      $toys = Toy::all();
      return response()->json([
         "toys" => $toys->toArray()
      ]);
    }
```

Petition get:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/toys", function(data){

        });
    });
    </script>
```

And i can see the data into the console:
 [image]

but how can show the info into HTML? thanks

Comment: you should learn some js/jQuery about how to manipulate dom. Or you shouldn't use json, just use html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use need to use `.` operator to get access data in each object, since you have an array of objects you need to loop through each object and access them as following example:

`data.id` - for accessing the id 
`data.genre` - for accessing the genre etc.

You can loop through the data object as following example in jquery

```
$(data).each( function (key, value) )
{
         $("#iddiv").append(value.id+","); //this will show all the ids in the div with id iddiv, which are separated by commas
}

<body>
        <div id= "iddiv" > </div>
</body>
```

**Edited:**

It is a two dimensional object so do the below thing

```
$(data).each( function (key, value) )
{
        $(value).each( function( key2, value2 )){

         $("#iddiv").append(value2.id+","); //this will show all the ids in the div with id iddiv, which are separated by commas

         })
}
```

Comment: ok , I did but only shows undefined,                                                                                        thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly is it showing undefined? Did you put the above code in your `function(data) { .. }`  part of the code?

Comment: In my view in <div id= "iddiv"></div> show undefined,

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

   $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/generos", function(data){
    
    $(data).each( function (key, value) {
     
            $("#iddiv").append(value.genre+","); //this will show all the ids in the div with id iddiv, which are separated by commas
    });
    
   });
  });

Comment: remove the semi colon from `"localhost:8000/generos";, ` part of the code

Comment: please check what exactly is undefined, is it the data variable that is undefined?

Comment: When i change to single $("#iddiv").append(value+","); i  see [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] and when add the .id i see undefined,

Comment: It is the index of the object that you are on, you might need it sometimes to track the index of the object.

Comment: Hi, i have other question xD, how can refresh this petition? for example Every 3 seconds? , because i use -> setInterval("carga()",500); but single duplicate my data